# How do I animate a beamer slide using elements from outside a list?

Tags: beamer, itemize

What I'm trying to do is have elements of a bulleted list appear in order, but then before the list is complete, make a table appear, then the rest of the list. My attempt to do this is here:

```
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.7\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}[(I)]
        \item<1-> Some Text
        \item<2-> Some text 

        \item<3-> More text
        \item<4-> Text I want to display after displaying the table below
    \end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}{.3\textwidth}
\begin{table}<3->
%I want this to display before the end of the list
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ c || c c c } 
 {} &     A      &        B        &  C  \\ 
\hline \hline
 A  & $\varepsilon$   &        -1       &  1  \\ 
 B  &     1      &    $\varepsilon$     &  -1 \\ 
 C  &     -1      &       1        & $\varepsilon$
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: @JasperHabicht Beamer does not have a floating mechanism, using `table` won't make the table float, it is perfectly safe to use it in beamer.

Comment: Using a `table` has two advantages: the caption you already mentioned and it will automatically centre the content and thus saves the user from having to use `\centering` all the time.

Answer (score 2):

Beamer columns are overlay aware, so you can make the whole column containing the table appear on the 3rd overlay.

Please also note that you don't need `\centering`, beamer will automatically centre the content of a `table` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{.7\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}[(I)]
        \item<1-> Some Text
        \item<2-> Some text 

        \item<3-> More text
        \item<4-> Text I want to display after displaying the table below
    \end{itemize}
\end{column}

\begin{column}<3->{.3\textwidth}
\begin{table}
%I want this to display before the end of the list
%\centering
\begin{tabular}{ c || c c c } 
 {} &     A      &        B        &  C  \\ 
\hline \hline
 A  & $\varepsilon$   &        -1       &  1  \\ 
 B  &     1      &    $\varepsilon$     &  -1 \\ 
 C  &     -1      &       1        & $\varepsilon$
 \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}


    
\end{document}
```

[image]